# Moving mySQL data to postgres, using a PostgreSQL schema file

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL schema file, and I have an SQL dump from a MySQL database. I want to know how I can import my MySQL dump file into Postgresql, using the postgresql schema file.

Answer (score 0):

You cna't direct restore mysql dump file into postgres

You use psotgresql wiki or specific software trasnfer like:

1. [Postgresql wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL)
2. [ESF Database Migration Toolkit](https://www.easyfrom.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you install another MySQL, load the dump there, and export the data in CSV format? This should allow you to load the data into PostgreSQL, using the COPY command.